# why the photo does not appear although I have written the complete path in database?

Tags: php, database, image, url, store

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKna7.jpg)

is there any wrong in the path? if there is .. so how to write valid image path in mysql database ? note that i am using php..The image above contains the colume of image which contains the paths of my images like C:/wamp/www/phpT/images/products/man.png

first of all I store the image by the complete path of it like this :

```
$uploadName=md5(microtime()).'.'.$mimeExten;
    $uploadPath='C:/wamp/www/phpT/images/products/'.$uploadName;
    $dbPath='C:/wamp/www/phpT/images/products/'.$uploadName;
    move_uploaded_file($fileTempLoc,$uploadPath);

    $insertSql="INSERT INTO products (title,price,list_price,brand,categories,image,description,sizes)
    VALUES ('$title','$price','$list_price','$brand','$category','$dbPath','$description','$sizes')";
    $db->query($insertSql);
```

Then I get it from the data base but it does not appear

Comment: gee I honestly don't know; do any of you other readers looking at what they posted know? *heh*

Comment: That isn't a URL.

Comment: @Don'tPanic not even "technically"? heh

Comment: link or url anyhow...what is the proper way of this ?

Comment: absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: `C:/wamp/www/phpT/images/products/man.png` is a path not a url

Comment: C: indicates windows, but you are using slashes not backslashes - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are local file paths, not URLs.  The file paths aren't going to work as image sources in a web page.

You'll need to replace `C:/wamp/www/` with something that points at your web server instead of your file system, like `http://localhost/` for your local dev environment.

The exact URL depends on your web server configuration, whether you're using a framework or otherwise rewriting URLs, and other various info we don't have about your specific installation.

If you store just the filename, and fill in the rest of the URL and path in your application, it will give you more flexibility with those resources in the future. As it is, you won't be able to change the directory structure at all without breaking your images again.

Comment: I would only add, that it's better to store only the file name, and then supply the path (base url) to the folder were files of this type are stored.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix agree to agree.

Comment: I have written  $uploadPath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/phpT/images/products/'.$uploadName; and it works well .. thank u